# Case statement formatting issues

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
select distinct 
    b.BinName, Si.Code, si.Name, 
    b.ConfirmedQtyInStock + b.UnconfirmedQtyInStock as StockQty, 
    AllocationPriority,
    Case 
       When r1.BinName = b.BinName Then r2.BinName 
       Else r1.BinName 
    End as [Location1], 
    Case 
       When r1.BinName = b.BinName Then r2.Qty 
       Else r1.Qty 
    End as [Qty1], 
    Case 
       When r2.BinName In (b.BinName, r1.BinName) Then r3.BinName 
       Else r2.BinName 
    End as [Location2]
from 
    BinItem b 
Inner Join 
    StockItem si On si.ItemID = b.ItemID
left outer join 
    (select 
         ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By si.Code Order By si.Code, ConfirmedQtyInStock + UnconfirmedQtyInStock asc) as ranking,
         si.Code, bi.BinName, 
         bi.ConfirmedQtyInStock + bi.UnconfirmedQtyInStock as Qty  
     from 
         stockitem si 
     inner join 
         binitem bi on bi.ItemID = si.itemid
     where 
         bi.ConfirmedQtyInStock + bi.UnconfirmedQtyInStock > 0) r1 On r1.ranking = 1 and r1.Code = si.Code 
left outer join 
    (select 
         ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By si.Code Order By si.Code, ConfirmedQtyInStock+UnconfirmedQtyInStock asc) as ranking,
         si.Code, bi.BinName, 
         bi.ConfirmedQtyInStock + bi.UnconfirmedQtyInStock as Qty  
     from 
         stockitem si 
     inner join 
         binitem bi on bi.ItemID = si.itemid
     where 
         bi.ConfirmedQtyInStock + bi.UnconfirmedQtyInStock > 0) r2 On r2.ranking = 2 and r2.Code = si.Code
left outer join 
    (select 
         ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By si.Code Order By si.Code, ConfirmedQtyInStock+UnconfirmedQtyInStock asc) as ranking,
         si.Code, bi.BinName, 
         bi.ConfirmedQtyInStock + bi.UnconfirmedQtyInStock as Qty  
     from 
         stockitem si 
     inner join 
         binitem bi on bi.ItemID = si.itemid
     where 
         bi.ConfirmedQtyInStock + bi.UnconfirmedQtyInStock > 0) r3 On r3.ranking = 3 and r3.Code = si.Code 
left outer join 
    (select 
         ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By si.Code Order By si.Code, ConfirmedQtyInStock + UnconfirmedQtyInStock asc) as ranking,
         si.Code, bi.BinName, 
         bi.ConfirmedQtyInStock + bi.UnconfirmedQtyInStock as Qty  
     from 
         stockitem si 
     inner join 
         binitem bi on bi.ItemID = si.itemid
     where 
         bi.ConfirmedQtyInStock + bi.UnconfirmedQtyInStock > 0) r4 On r4.ranking = 4 and r4.Code = si.Code 
Where 
    si.StockItemStatusID = 0 
    and ConfirmedQtyInStock + UnconfirmedQtyInStock > 0
    and si.code = '06403107C' 
Order By 
    Code, b.BinName
```

What I am trying to do is to ensure that only unique locations are in each of the columns. For example:

```
C03B1   06403107C   1 1/4in COUNTER NUT CHROME PLATED BRASS 543.00000   1
    C04A1   9.00000
C04A1   06403107C   1 1/4in COUNTER NUT CHROME PLATED BRASS 9.00000 4
    C03B1   543.00000
```

However I haven't quite worked out the case logic to move all the values in the r1,r2,r3,r4 subqueries correctly.

Comment: Please show us the input (output?) data which is missing.

Comment: BinName=C04A1             Code=06403107C                                            BinName=C03B1             Code=06403107C                               BinName=ZGOODSIN     Code=06403107C